# Searching a word in multiple file type

Tags: notepad++

I have two questions in notepad++..

1. I am having problem in searching a function which can be in any file format(for ex: *.c *.h *.ec *.sh etc)..
   I know in notepad++ there is a option to search in file (find in files Ctrl+Shift+f) but how to provide multiple file format?
2. When i double click on a word all the matching words gets highlighted. But when i select two or three characters of that word the corresponding matching characters are not highlighted. is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Question 1:

- Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- In the filter field, type: `*.c;*.h;*.ec;*.sh` or nothing if you don't want to filter.

Question 2:

I don't think that is possible.

Comment: thanks..

in other editor ques 2 works .. is there any plugin to do this?

Comment: @Grv: Sorry, I don't know :( May be you could find something here: https://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: @Grv: regarding Question 2: when the part is selected: use Search -> Mark All -> Using 1st Style  or one of the other styles. Or you could use Search -> Mark ...

Comment: @LarsFischer i am currently doing the same thing but i thought might be there is a plugin for it.. neways thanks

Comment: I have tried "txt, xml", "*.(txt|xml)"... didn't expect it's so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding highlighting any set of selected characters across the file (the second question): in "Settings->Highlighting->Smart Highlighting->Matching" uncheck the "Match whole word only" option.